# C# program quitting/crashing suddenly, how to break it?

Tags: c#

So my C# program is quitting/disapearing/closing/crashing suddenly even in debug mode.
How can I make it break/pause/stop so as to find out where caused it?

Comment: FYI, this is strongly characteristic of code which double-faults the stack. Do you have any unmanaged code running in your process that might be faulting the last page of the stack? Do you have unbounded recursions?

Answer (score 5):

Set a breakpoint (by clicking the left of the line numbers--it's a red circle) that you know is before the point where it crashes and then step through it (using F8). The last statement that you're on is the one that it's crashing at.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in Visual Studio you can enable "Stop when an exception is thrown" - go Debug->Exceptions. This is often quite useful for detecting the exact source of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to learn more by using an [unhandled exception handler](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/unhandledexceptions.aspx). However, if you're in debug mode you should be able to see it by default. Check your Debug: Exceptions settings to make sure you haven't accidentally stopped reporting them in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

as Eric suggested try going through step through it... also always place try/catch in your end caller apps in order to manage exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it may be worth checking your code for occurrences of [Environment.FailFast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx), just in case someone tried to be (too) smart.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit F10 to start debugging your project. This will put a breakpoint right at the beginning of your Main method, then you can go from there stepping through the code with F11 to see at which points it crashes.